# Why few questions appear in different background?

Tags: support

Few questions in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active appear in different background. What does the different background mean?

Comment: Is it orange background? If orange, it is due to favorite tags. See [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes, but whose favorite... mine or anyone who marked them favorite?

Comment: if you have set some tags as favorites, then questions under those appear as orange background.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ok, got it... these are questions from my favorite tags... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, I understand that they are questions tagged with one of your favorite tags. Questions with favorite tags are shown in yellow like below. tags [hanuman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hanuman) and [vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vishnu) are in the list of my favorite tags.

[image: Pic showing favorite tag.]

There are also ignored tags. Questions tagged with these are shown grey by default but you can also choose to hide them. For demonstration, I ignored [marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage).

[image: Pic with ignored tag]

You can select your preferences from your profile page and edit it.

For more details, see [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/357396) .